# Extract AM/PM column from a POSIXct object?

Tags: r, time, posixct

if i have a dataset with a column of **POSIXct** timestamps e.g. my dataframe looks like this

```
df$time
    
16/07/2020 07:35
16/07/2020 08:42
16/07/2020 12:21
16/07/2020 13:07
16/07/2020 14:27
```

I would like to keep this timestamp but create an AM/PM column, that is a seperate column and not the %p in the strptime or lubridate package.

I would like the result to look like this:

```
df
  1                    2
16/07/2020 07:35       AM
16/07/2020 08:42       AM
16/07/2020 12:21       PM
16/07/2020 13:07       PM
16/07/2020 14:27       PM
```

Is there a way to do this for a posixct timetamp?

Thank you

Comment: `strftime(df$time, format = "%p")`?

Answer (score 1):

First note that contrary to what is stated in the question the data shown there  is not in POSIXct form or else it would not display like that.  Questions are supposed to provide the data in reproducible form and since that was not done we have provided it in the Note at the end.

**1) format.POSIXct** Using the input in the Note at the end, convert to POSIXct and then format using `%p`:

```
datetime <- as.POSIXct(L, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
format(datetime, "%p")
## [1] "AM" "AM" "PM" "PM" "PM"
```

**2) character manip** Another possibility is to use pure character mannipulation:

```
ifelse(sub(".* ", "", L) < "12:00", "AM", "PM")
## [1] "AM" "AM" "PM" "PM" "PM"
```

or

```
ifelse(substring(L, 12) < "12:00", "AM", "PM")
## [1] "AM" "AM" "PM" "PM" "PM"
```

or

```
ifelse(read.table(text = L)$V2 < "12:00", "AM", "PM")
## [1] "AM" "AM" "PM" "PM" "PM"
```

### Note

```
# test input
L <- c("16/07/2020 07:35", "16/07/2020 08:42", "16/07/2020 12:21", 
  "16/07/2020 13:07", "16/07/2020 14:27")
```